# Deploying Django app : Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I was deploying my django app on my VPS using the apache web server.
It works totally fine on `http://192.46.209.82:8000/` but when I try to access the same using my IP address, `192.46.209.82`. I get

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.46.209.82 Port 80
```

Here is my conf file

**nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /root/django/myproject
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Alias /static /root/django/myproject/static
        <Directory /root/django/myproject/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /root/django/myproject/myproject>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/root/django/myproject python-home=/root/django/myprojectenv
        WSGIProcessGroup myproject
        WSGIScriptAlias / /root/django/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using python's virtual environment, where myprojectenv is my virtual env path and the pwd is `/root/django`

[image]

**Note :** I tried the answer from the question that I was getting as suggestion to this question but that did not work for me.

**EDIT :** Updated permission

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case even though I set up all the permission correctly, I still was getting error so I moved my entire project and virtual environment to `/opt` and it worked for me for now. But I would like to know the reason why it was not working under `/home` even when I gave all permissions

Comment: It was because the home folder did not the search/execute permission set for others . `chmod o+x /home/username` would run django. But it better be not in your home folder anyway.